# PHP Parse error caused by SVG

Tags: php, svg, openshift

I have [this SVG](http://pastie.org/9713141) on the server. Everything is fine, until I try to use PHP to include it into my page. When I do that, it causes 503 errors to appear on all pages, not just the one I have the SVG included on. When I use `rhc tail` to see what's going on, I get this:

```
[Tue Nov 11 19:47:37 2014] [error] [client <ip>] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'encoding' (T_STRING) in /var/lib/openshift/<undisclosed>/app-root/runtime/repo/images/svg/monitor.svg on line 1
```

This does not happen on my local (Linux) server.

Comment: What's the output with the PHP if you don't try to open it as an SVG? There might be a problem there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have PHP short tags enabled, so it's trying to parse it as a PHP file.

You can disable this in a number of ways. php.ini is your best option: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Sorry, missed the openshift tag. Try `/php/configuration/etc/php.ini`, otherwise you can add a rule to an `.htaccess` file: `php_value short_open_tag 0`

Comment: editing `php/configuration/etc/php.ini` worked, thanks. Accepting your answer ;)

Comment: I just got bit by this on WPEngine, which inexplicably still has short_open_tag enabled (for a site created just last year). Their documentation says to add the flag to .user.ini, but that didn't work for me - adding to .htaccess did, though.